# Inserting aggregates into big table is too slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, sql-insert

I need to run a query as cronjob and it is too slow to perform. It sums a value from a view table (`data_time_series`) for each pair of `aks` and `ii` and inserts a row in `storage_time_series` if those values are not present there yet:
Here is the query:

```
INSERT INTO storage_time_series (time, value, akd, ii)
SELECT data.time, data.value, data.akd, data.ii FROM
   ( SELECT 
        now() AS time,
        SUM(value) AS value,
        labels[2] AS akd,
        labels[4] AS ii
    FROM data_time_series
    GROUP BY akd, ii) AS data
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM storage_time_series AS dst WHERE dst.value = data.value AND dst.access_key_id = data.akd AND dst.instance_id = data.ii );
```

The first part of the query produces around 200K rows and is fast:

```
SELECT 
        now() AS time,
        SUM(nullif(value, 'NaN'))  AS value,
        labels[2] AS akd,
        labels[4] AS ii
    FROM public.data_time_series
    GROUP BY akd, ii
```

The second part of the query checks if the data exists in `storage_time_series`. This part is too slow:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM storage_time_series AS dst WHERE dst.value = data.value AND dst.access_key_id = data.akd AND dst.instance_id = data.ii)
```

`storage_time_series` is a huge table and I need to keep the data and `akd` and `ii` are indexed on `storage_time_series`.

Here is the tables schema:

```
SELECT version() :
PostgreSQL 12.9 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.3.1_git20211027) 10.3.1 20211027, 64-bit
```

```
CREATE TABLE storage_time_series
(
    "time" timestamp with time zone,
    value double precision,
    akd integer,
    ii integer
)

CREATE  INDEX 
    ON storage_time_series USING btree
    (akd ASC NULLS LAST, ii ASC NULLS LAST, value ASC NULLS LAST)
```

Number of rows on **storage_time_series** table: ~190 million
**data_time_series** is a view and has about 1.3 million rows.

Is there any way to speed up this process?

**EDITED:** I've already tested creating `unique index` over **akd**, **ii** and **value** and changed query to simple **INSERT** and **ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING**, but seems having `unique index` make insert process very slower than before.

Comment: Usual inserts go like: insert some rows, on conflict do something(ignore). Why did you insert rows like this? Is there some reason for such insert query?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I need to have older values for each pair of akd and ii. The query is checking if value is changed then insert the new one with new timestamp on storage_time_series table.

Comment: Please provide proper information for a performance question. Exact table and index definitions, Postgres version, output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, ... See instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: You can use an `index`, as in the answer, or create a `constraint` and use it in `insert` statement.

Comment: @user14063792468 I did it, but inserting with unique index on a huge table was slower than before.

Comment: If you edit your question, please leave some remarks, like **Edit** or **Update**. SO users are humans like you and me. They answer a question as it is written and leave it behind. If you made an edits, readers must know that information had changed. The answer may be **very** different, based on a new information.

Comment: I wrote the above because I had missed, or it were not in OP, that you have a system that is not "common" to DBMS'es. > x86_64-pc-linux-musl - tell me that it is some sly system, maybe embedded.

Comment: I do not understand how is inserting by index can be slower then making a bunch of comparisons. Well, it can in one situation, and can not in other... You do not give a full information needed.

Comment: @user14063792468 Thanks for your response and sorry for the confusion I caused, I installed TimescaleDB as a container docker on AWS EC2, so it does not install directly on the operating system, the system has 8 cores and 64G RAM, TimescaleDB is an extension for postgres  and postgres version is 12.9 , Is there anything else I should mention here?

Comment: @user14063792468 I tried the way that **erwin-brandstetter** mentioned on the answers, it worked but seems the inserting process takes longer, when I googled the problem I found out making unique index can cause this. I'm not a DB expert so I have no Idea why inserting is takes more than comparisons, is there anything else I can check?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244725/discussion-between-sma-and-user14063792468).

Comment: See what others wrote.

Answer (score 1):

> `akd` and `ii` are indexed on `storage_time_series`

Sounds good. But too vague to say more. If, as it seems, `(akd, ii, value)` is supposed to be unique, create a `UNIQUE INDEX` accordingly:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON storage_time_series (akd, ii, value);
```

Then your query burns down to:

```sql
INSERT INTO storage_time_series
      (akd      , ii       , value     , time )
SELECT labels[2], labels[4], sum(value), now())
FROM   data_time_series
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ON     CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Which *should* be fast. Much depends undisclosed details.

Comment: I did this but this time the insert time become too much, seems having unique indexes is not good for mass insert. :(